# Flutter / FireStore: how to display an image from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I want to put some images that I use in my app to Firestore, and display them from there, rather than having them as assets, bundled in my app.

In order to do this, I came up with the following solution: for the item I want to display an image, I created a Firebase document, where I have a field that stores the name of the file that stores the corresponding picture:

```
document
- name
- description
- imageName
```

Then, I uploaded an image to FireStore with the same name.

When I want to display the image, I can successfully get the document via StreamBuilder, and extract the imageName property.

I also created the necessary FireStore references:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage(
    storageBucket: 'gs://osszefogasaszanhuzokert.appspot.com/'
  );
StorageReference imageLink = storage.ref().child('giftShopItems').child(documentSnapshot['imageName']);
```

However, I can't seem to pass it to an `Image.network()` widget.

Is it possible to display an image the way I'd like to, or should I use a different Image provider?

Comment: So did you access your pictures from "Storage"  ? If so, why did you create a field called "imgeName" under your document? I believe that field cannot reference the image stored under "Storage" right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `.getDownloadURL()` from the StorageReference `imageLink` to get the storage URL link:

```
final imageUrl = await imageLink.getDownloadUrl();
Image.network(imageUrl.toString());
```