# How to display image file in firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I found following issue. Then I understand it.

[Flutter / FireStore: how to display an image from Firestore in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836339/flutter-firestore-how-to-display-an-image-from-firestore-in-flutter)

File uploading is succeeding.

```
var imgUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
print(imgUrl.toString());
```

However I have following error.
It seems I'm doing same.

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error -13010, FIRStorageErrorDomain, Object images/cars/40711b90-9db4-11ea-c602-a557c9b7697a.jpeg does not exist.)

However I have no idea how to display and handle it.

Please give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have image store in FireBaseStorage and that image have proper Rules given to access them?

Comment: I am trying with same application. Rules should be same. `rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: enter image path your browser and  check image is shown or not, if shown everything is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the url to firestore first:

```
          StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await storage
              .ref()
              .child("images/$imageName")
              .putFile(file)
              .onComplete;
          if (snapshot.error == null) {
            final String downloadUrl =
                await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            await Firestore.instance
                .collection("images")
                .add({"url": downloadUrl, "name": imageName});
             }
```

Now in Firestore you will have collection called `images` and document with the image url and image name. The method `getDownloadUrl()` returns the url of the image so you can store it in Firestore. Then to display it you can do the following:

```
body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getImages(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                title:
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                leading: Image.network(
                    snapshot.data.documents[index].data["url"],
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              );
            });
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
        return Text("No data");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
),

/// code here

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getImages() {
    return fb.collection("images").getDocuments();
  }
```

Here you use the method `getImages()` which retrieves all the images from the collection `images`. To display the image you can use `Image.network` widget.

Comment: I might take wrong design to store data in firestore. I don't have good idea to specify  images. How should I hold url data in firestore?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I would like to upload image into firestrage. Then retrieve the image soon to show. However now I have http URL in firedatabase.

Comment: The above code does exactly what you want, `putFile` is adding the image in firebase storage, `add()` is creating the document with the url of the image in firebase storage. In the second part of the code the image is retrieved and shown in the screen

Comment: The code is from this tutorial https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/05/06/using-firebase-storage-in-flutter/ , source code: https://github.com/PeterHdd/Firebase-Storage-Tutorial

Comment: I'm wandering what if I have URL data as `Image.network( snapshot.data.documents[index].data["url"],` as `https://xxxx` normal URL, it might be wrong way.

Comment: How can I hold URL data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214526/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-tajihiro).